# Why is Fourier space not adecuate for (theoretical) filters?

Tags: filter

As far as I have seen, almost all theoretical filter design occurs in Laplace or Z-space.
Also, there is a pervasive connection to real life analog filters in the design. If one
is just thinking in a mathematical theoretical thing (or something that could be implemented digitally), why wouldn't one filter signals in Fourier Space?

Why is, say, multiplying the Fourier Transform of a certain function by a unit step up - step down function, and then making the Inverse Transform of the resulting signal a "band pass filter"?
Why should one use Butterworth or similar things to make a digital filter?

Comment: dsp.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Comment: Okey, I shall repost it there. Thanks.

Comment: I see this question lives over on dsp  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70754/why-is-fourier-space-not-adequate-for-theoretical-or-digital-filters

Comment: This was cross posted to dsp some time ago, where it sits much better. It should have been removed here. Closing now in any case.

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical point of view representing signals as Fourier- or Laplace-analysis is equivalent in the sense, that you come to the same conclusions. The matheamtics and operations are very similar.

However, in terms of circuit design using Laplace makes things more easy. E.g. you can calculate transfer functions of passive networks (using resistors, inductances and capacitors, and just expressing their complex impedances in Laplace form). Once you know it mathematically, you know everything about that circuits performance, e.g. in response to white noise, to dirac pulses, step-functions and so on.

With digital filters you trade one disease for an other one:

- you get rid of analog limitations (like aging, drift, cost)
- in return you obtain a host or artefacts (it was, is, and reamins digital, i.e. provides complex spectra)

So in filter design you need to balance at least:

- requirements from (ideal) signal processing
- dealing with said artefacts (broad and often nasty spectra)
- side effects, like EMC (may be less in the filter, but from passing it's artefacts via all lines to more power processing units, like output stages)

Yes, digital signal processing can be a nightmare.

Comment: Hi - I'm going to delete this question, so do you want to post this answer over on the other version at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70754/why-is-fourier-space-not-adequate-for-theoretical-or-digital-filters

Comment: Hm, not going to open just another membership for now. If you feel it‘s a useful answer over there it‘s ok with me to shift or copy it.